# how to use C preprocessor to overload function return types (in C only)

Tags: c

There are several ways to overload C functions based on input parameters but none that I have found that will overload C function return values.

Consider the following for `char*` input that returns either a `float` or `long`

Used as

```
long myLval = to_num("65");

float myFval = to_num("34.67");
```

To overload the return type would require the ability of the preprocessor to parse the input string for a period and replace the `to_num` macro with either `to_numF` or `to_numL`.

In pseudo code

```
(#)define to_num(A) ("A" contains period == true) ? to_numF(A) : to_numL(A);

long to_numL(long val) {long rVal; sprintf(&rVal, "%ld", val); return rVal; }

float to_numF(float val) {float rVal; sprintf(&rVal, "%ld", val); return rVal; }
```

Looking for a way to identify the period in the macro argument parameter and test for its presence. (Optionally, it might be able to add a token to the input string and test for the token.  Though possibly doable not desirable.)

Comment: you can implement polymorphic objects in C, but that's about the best you'll get. What are the several ways you claim?

Comment: what? you're sprintfing into a pointer to long, float? That doesn't work at all. Perhaps you meant strtod, strtol?

Comment: C11's [`_Generic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) _might_ help.

Comment: Also how is this supposed to work with variables? If you take a string (possibly containing user input) and call `to_num()` with it as parameter, which version is it supposed to use?

Comment: @tuple_cat Realy?

Comment: In C (contrary to C++) there's no way to check whether a string literal contains `'.'` at compile-time so this isn't possible.

Comment: The function serves little purpose if the input is always a literal-string and a compile time determination could not work for a string-variable.  So... why?   If you have to declare the type for the return value, it is little hardship to call the appropriate function.

Comment: Whats is the difference between your goal and  `long myLval = 65; 
float myFval = 34.67;`?

Comment: `"65"` is a perfectly good `float`. Just say no to appearance-based discrimination.

Comment: A further complication is that the `?:` operator has a result type determined at compile time. The C99 standard says *If both the second and third operands have arithmetic type, the result type that would be
determined by the usual arithmetic conversions, were they applied to those two operands, is the type of the result.*. So you would always get the result converted to a common type, probably `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The c preprocessor is - to my knowledge - not capable of parsing string literals, so there is, as mentioned by tuble_cat, no way to do this in c.

However, if you simply use `strtod`, which converts strings to double data type, together with implicit type casts you can still do the conversions with (as I assume) the desired effects:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ()
{
    int xi = strtod("34",NULL);
    double xd = strtod("34.35",NULL);
    int xi_d = strtod("34.35",NULL);
    printf("integer:%d, double:%lf, double assigned to int:%d",xi,xd,xi_d);   
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
integer:34, double:34.350000, double assigned to int:34
```

Comment: I think it may be possible to combine the C11 __Generic keyword with macro to obtain the disired effect. Anyway, that really stupid to try to transform the C language in something else...

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do almost what you want by using the _Generic keyword introduced in C11, **BUT I would no advise to do this**. Indeed, C is meant to be super simple and you always know the type of your variable, so why bother trying to create a generic function ? It has only a meaning when the name of the function should really come naturally to the programmer, like `cos` or `sqrt` but for any other functions the programmer should read/know the doc and use the function that has the appropriate type.

In addition, generic functions in C kinda break the C syntax. Nobody is used to them.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define strtoAny(string, X) X = _Generic((X), \
    long double: strtold(string, NULL), \
    double: atof(string), \
    float: strtof(string, NULL), \
    long long: atoll(string), \
    long: atol(string), \
    int: atoi(string), \
    short: atoi(string), \
    char: atoi(string), \
    long long unsigned: strtoull(string, NULL, 10), \
    long unsigned: strtoul(string, NULL, 10), \
    unsigned: strtoul(string, NULL, 10), \
    unsigned short: strtoul(string, NULL, 10), \
    unsigned char: strtoul(string, NULL, 10), \
    default: atoi(string) \
    )


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    long double num;
    strtoAny("90.1",num);

    printf("%8Lf\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for an inline macro replacement such as

Comment: To clarify, I am looking for an inline C preprocessor replacement such as  toggling the value of numberone below manually does but need a way to set the value of numberone based on the macro argument containing a "."                                                                                          #define numberone 0
#if numberone == 2
#define to_number(a) to_numberF(a)
#elif numberone == 0
#define to_number(a) to_numberL(a)
#endif

Comment: The 'Answers' both confirm that the current C preprocessor cannot parse macro arguments which confirms my original findings.  Since posting this question I have learned that to parse macro arguments can be done by employing a more robust text macro such as M4.  The GNU M4 is one of several text macro processors that will parse macro arguments and subsequently alter the macro output.